# Bootstrap - alignment with label name and text box while shrinking the screen size

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to have the Label name on one row and textbox for that name in the second row, meaning, the textbox should be below the label for input.

I can achieve this using Bootstrap with a 3 column labels and 2 column textboxes in the fullscreen, but when i resize the screen, all my labels group up and then the corresponding textboxes below my labels.

My bootstrap code:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4" >
                 <strong>Patient’s Last name</strong> <span class="required">*</span>  
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4" >
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Patient_Lastname, new { @class = "text-primary", required = "required" })
             </div>
          
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <strong>Patient’s First name</strong> <span class="required">*</span> 
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Patient_Firstname, new { @class = "text-primary", required = "required" })
             </div>
         
                 <div class="col-md-4" >
                     <strong>Age</strong> <span class="required">*</span> 
                     </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4" >
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Age, new List<SelectListItem>
                 {
                     new SelectListItem{ Text="Under 18", Value = "Under 18"},
                     new SelectListItem{ Text="18-21", Value = "18-21"},
                     new SelectListItem{ Text="22-30", Value = "22-30"},
                 }, "--Select Age--", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", style = "width: 250px; height:30px;" })
                 </div>
             </div> 
          </div>
```

My **output as whole screen is**, which is perfect:
[image]

When I **shrink the screensize, it looks like this**:
[image]

But, the **desired output should look like**, when screen is resized to minimal :
[image]

Any thoughts on the html code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be defining the label and input in the same column:

```
<div class="col-md-4" >
    <strong>Patient’s Last name</strong> <span class="required">*</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Patient_Lastname, new { @class = "text-primary", required = "required" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <strong>Patient’s First name</strong> <span class="required">*</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Patient_Firstname, new { @class = "text-primary", required = "required" })
</div>
```

Comment: @Ron The above syntax places span and Textbox in same line instead of span Patients Last Name on top and Textbox on the bottom. I have a similar situation but if I use your code it places my label and textbox next to each other instead one of top and one on bottom.